Windows won't open most programs after startup (even Task Manager and CMD)
I've had this recurring issue where my computer doesn’t load most programs after startup. There’s a really short window (maybe a second or two) where I can click on a program and it’ll open, but it just stays unresponsive after that. Task Manager doesn’t open, and neither does cmd.
Some things, like File Explorer and the trash bin, do open, but if I try to open files from those menus, nothing happens. If I try opening something through Windows Explorer, after a while, I get an error message saying, "The app didn’t start in the required time."
I tried looking this up, but most of the fixes seem to need access to Task Manager or cmd, which I can’t use. Any ideas on what I should do next? Even just knowing what this issue is called so I can look it up would help a lot. Thanks!
P.S. I haven't had this problem in a while, it only reappeared after I installed steam again. Not sure if its a coincidence or not, but thought I'd mention it.
P.P.S. No way! I started the computer in Safe Mode and disabled Steam on startup. After that, my computer worked fine. Fingers crossed it stays that way!

Perform a repair install of Windows by downloading the Windows install ISO through the media creation tool, extracting the ISO to a folder, then run setup.exe while booted to Windows, choosing to Keep all files and settings. That should resolve the issue, but if not, create a new user and see if the issues persist (if not, it's a corrupted user profile - copy all data from the older user profile's user data directories [Documents, Downloads, etc.] to the new user's). If the issue still persists, run an offline antivirus and malware scan.

@JW0914 Is there an option that doesn't require reinstalling windows? I've done it multiple times (and it does work) but I feel like this is a bad solution if I have to do this everytime it happens.

A Repair Install isn't a Clean Install of Windows - it's how Windows is repaired when something severely goes wrong; it doesn't uninstall anything, you don't lose any data, and you shouldn't notice any difference except for the problem being resolved. A Repair Install and a version upgrade of Windows [24H1, 24H2, etc.] through Windows Update effectively use the exact same process, where the %WinDir% from the install.<esd|wim> is used to replace the OS files in the current install's %WinDir%, this is why setup.exe is launched while booted to Windows and not by booting an install USB.

(Cont'd...) For isolated problems that occur, Dism and Sfc can be used, however it's going to be more efficient [quicker] to simply do a Repair Install for the issues described since it only takes ~30min with an SSD, slightly longer with a mechanical HDD.

Also, try a thorough, offline malware scan with a onetime-use tool, e.g., https://www.lifewire.com/free-bootable-antivirus-tools-2625785 . It could be a cryptominer or other malware is using up CPU time.
